# Push return to parent function

Tags: r, return, environment

Is there a way how to force parent function to return an output? Say I have a function that 'does something' and at the beginning of each function a want to 'check something'. If the check fails I want to return 'something else'.

In my example below 'does something' is logarithm, 'check something' means checking that the variable is nonnegative and 'something else' is minus infinity.

```
weird_log <- function(x) {
  check(x)
  log(x)
}

check <- function(x) {
  if (x <= 0)
    eval.parent(parse(text = 'return(-Inf)'))
}
```

This example doesn't work

```
weird_log(10)  # 2.302585
weird_log(-10) # NaN
```

One solution is to return 'something else' from the check function if the checks find a problem and `NULL` otherwise. Then I can write one `if` in the parent function and it's done.

```
weird_log <- function(x) {
  y <- check(x)
  if (!is.null(y)) return(y)
  log(x)
}

check <- function(x) {
  if (x <= 0) {
    -Inf
  } else {
    NULL
  }
}
```

This solution still keeps most of the functionality in separated function `check()` but is there a way to have all the functionality in it?

---

In the real problem the checking function does more than just one comparison and it is used in multiple functions so it is necessary to have it separately. Also 'something else' that returns the `check` function depends on condition which the input fails.

---

More realistic example:

```
weird_log <- function(input) {
  y <- check(input)
  if (!is.null(y)) return(y)
  list(log = log(input$x))
}

check <- function(input) {
  if (is.null(input$x)) {
    list(error = 'x is missing')
  } else if (!is.numeric(input$x)) {
    list(error = 'x is not numeric')
  } else if (x <= 0) {
    list(log = -Inf, warn = 'x is not positive')
  } else {
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even need `parse(text = 'return(-Inf)')` there.  Won't `eval.parent(return(-Inf))` do the same thing? I don't know where you guys learn that, but it's really bad code practice.

Comment: Good point, I have overcomplicated it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the answer does not actually answer the question here is how to do what you asked.

```
returnFromParent <- function() {
  call <- rlang::expr(return()) 
  rlang::eval_bare(call, env = parent.frame())
}

foo <- function(){
  returnFromParent()
  print("you should not see this")
}

foo()
```

The only way I have found to do this is using rlang.

Answer (score 5):

[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

```
weird_log <- function(x) {
  if (check(x)) return(-Inf)
  log(x)
}

check <- function(x) {
  x <= 0
}

weird_log(10)  # 2.302585
weird_log(-10) # -Inf
```

More common is the use case where you want to throw an error when check fails:

```
weird_log <- function(x) {
  check(x)
  log(x)
}

check <- function(x) {
  if(x <= 0) stop("x <= 0", call. = FALSE)
}

weird_log(10)  # 2.302585
weird_log(-10) # Error: x <= 0
```

Comment: I didn't specify this but the output of the check may differ depending on several conditions inside. So the check cannot return simply `TRUE`/`FALSE`. I cannot use `stop()` either, errors are unacceptable for this problem.

Comment: That doesn't change my point. Return statements should always be part of the function you want to return from. check could, e.g., return an integer value and you could use switch in the parent function.

Comment: That's not answering the question. These sort of answers for wee badges are actually infuriating and detrimental to the community.

Comment: If you believe I care about some internet points, you are sadly mistaken. I care about not promoting bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an other version of JohnCoene's solution without relying on rlang:

```r
returnFromParent <- function(env = parent.frame()) {
  do.call(return, list("a"), envir = env)
}

foo <- function() {
  returnFromParent()
  "b"
}

stopifnot(foo() == "a")
```