# Conditionally modifying behaviour of parent function

Tags: r, function, namespaces, call, evaluation

## Background

I'm interested in returning an object to parent frame of function and stoping execution of the parent function *without* an error.

### Notes

I went through some of the discussions [on related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42858804/1655567) on the SO and agree with a wider point that this is not necessarily best practice. I'm mostly interested in doing this for educational purposed and gaining better understanding of how to make use of the [function call stack](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sys.parent.html).

## Reproducible example

### `check_conditions`

This function is expected to check conditions and in some specific case return results to the parent function.

```
check_conditions <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is.numeric(x),
              x %% 1 == 0)
    # And for x == 9 always return 9
    if (x == 9) {
        eval.parent(return(1))
        stop()
    }
}
```

### Other functions

The remaining functions make use of the `check_conditions` function and do their own stuff later on (or not, if stopped).

```
fun_a <- function(x) {
    check_conditions(x)
    x^2
}

fun_b <- function(x) {
    check_conditions(x)
    x+1
}
```

## Problem

```
>> fun_b(1)
[1] 2

>> fun_a(9)
[1] 81

>> fun_b(9)
[1] 10
```

In the example above I would like for the `fun_a` and `fun_b` to return value **`1`**, as per the condition:

```
if (x == 9) {
            eval.parent(return(1))
            stop()
        }
```

## Notes

- I don't want to return an error message. There **should be no message** indicating that the remaining calls across `fun_a` and `fun_b` were not processed.

### Update *(as per comments)*

- I don't want to change the body of `fun_a` or `fun_b`, `check_conditions` can be changed.
- It should be possible to change behaviour of a hypothetical `fun_n` that also makes reference to `check_conditions` *without* editing that function. `check_conditions` should be able to return and stop *(without error or warning)* and return value in parent enviornment of the function, *R-ish* pseudocode

  ```
  check_conditions <- function(x) {
  if (x == 9) {
     call(env = parent.frame(),
          expr = {
                  return(1)
                  # Do not execute anything else from 
                  # the parent environment.
          }
    }
   }
  ```

Comment: Can you instead of using `fun_a` and `fun_b` use `wrapped_fun_a` and `wrapped_fun_b` to make the modifications you want?  It just seems hard for me to think of exactly why you need to take the approach you're trying to take.

Comment: @Dason Possibly, it more conceptual/workflow question. Let's assume that I've *n* function doing different things all of those reference `check_condition`. I would like to modify `check_condition` so I change behaviour of those functions without touching them. I admin, it's slightly unorthodox and this is not something I would do for other than experimental purposes. I'm curious whether someone can come up with solution that would deliver that result.

Comment: Honestly that sounds like something that I would explicitly not want.  If you want to be able to control what happens to those functions without having to explicitly modify them then I would think wrapping them and adding an additional parameter to the wrapper to allow you to change things would be a better approach.  But having code that can alter how another function operates without touching that function at all seems... messy. And that's pretty much the exact reason why people rail against global variables too since they make things less functional.

Comment: @Dason Agreed 100% concerning the potentially adverse implications, and I wouldn't implement this solution a production code. This is purely a fun/curiosity question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is revised from older answer.  It does not require that `check_conditions` or `fun_a` be changed but does require that:

- `fun_a` be registered via a call such as `fun_a <- validity_check(fun_a)` after which `fun_a` can be used
- the call to `check_conditions` must be the first line of the body
- check_conditions takes the same arguments as `fun_a`

Code:

```
validity_check <- function(fun) {
   cl <- body(fun)[[2]][[1]]
   function(...) {
     mc <- match.call()
     mc[[1]] <- cl
     check_val <- eval.parent(mc)
     if (!is.null(check_val)) check_val
     else fun(...) 
   }
}

# test - fun_a and check_conditions as in question

fun_a <- validity_check(fun_a)

fun_a(9)
## [1] 1

fun_a(2)
## [1] 4
```

**Older answer** I am not clear on what can be changed and what cannot be but if we can modify all functions then:

```
check_conditions <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is.numeric(x), x %% 1 == 0)
    if (x == 9) structure(1, class = "bad")
}

fun_a <- function(x) {
  cc <- check_conditions(x)
  if (inherits(cc, "bad")) unclass(cc) else x^2
}

fun_a(9)
## [1] 1

fun_a(2)
## [1] 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, I should make my question clearer. What I wanted to do is to call `return(1)` in parent function env. if condition within `check_condition` is met. So I wouldn't like to change the body of `fun_a` and `fun_b`. In a sentence, if ` x == 9` then: *1)* remaining lines of `fun_a` and `fun_c` are not executed, *2)* outputs is `1` *3)* there are no errors or warning messages. To clarify `check_conditions` can be changed, `fun_a` and `fun_b` ***can't*** be changed.

Comment: OK. Have revised.

Comment: Thanks; smart answer. Accepted, ideally I would avoid calling `fun_a <- validity_check(fun_a)` but it's smart approach. I was also thinking of drawing on [this answer](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-stop-without-error-message-td866604.html) to silent the `stop` error message but I reckon that your solution is better.